# Import and use external Typescript module in Vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, node-modules

I'm pretty new to Vue and am trying to use an external Typescript module in my Vue Component to render a guitar fretboard (https://github.com/omnibrain/svguitar). Ideally I would like to be able to render these in different locations of my application. I've followed the steps in the `ReadMe.md` but can't get it to work.
This is what my component looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="chart" />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { SVGuitarChord } from "svguitar";

const chart = new SVGuitarChord("#chart");

export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    console.log("I'm mounted");
    chart
      .configure({
        strings: 6,
        frets: 5
      })
      .chord({
        fingers: [],
        barres: []
      })
      .draw();
  }
});
</script>
```

Doing this, I receive the following error in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of null
    at Svg.addTo (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:2746)
    at new SvgJsRenderer (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:7478)
    at SVGuitarChord.get (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:7654)
    at SVGuitarChord.clear (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:8021)
    at SVGuitarChord.draw (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:7685)
    at VueComponent.mounted (Home.vue?42b8:20)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4219)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3139)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6346)
```

Would be great if somebody could heb me out to get this to work! If any additional information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because you specify `#chart` as container to `SVGuitarChord` but you write `<div class="chart" />`. It should be `<div id="chart" />`

Comment: My goodness.... Can't believe I missed that. Thanks hackape!

Comment: You’re welcome. A piece of advice here, learn to read the error stack. You can check into code at `Svg.addTo (svguitar.es5.js?98dc:2746)` and see what exactly goes wrong there. Usually you can have a good guess of reason by simply looking at the code around where the error is thrown.